# Creating an entity association using rest

Tags: json, rest, dynamics-crm-2011

update: [Here is the marketing list entity metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309315.aspx). Scroll down and you can see the Many-To-Many relationships, there you can see the listcontact_association that I am trying to use.

I am trying to associate a contact with a marketing list. This is what I am trying to use(basically POST a json with the uri):

```
 curl --ntlm -u username:password -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"uri":"http://hostname/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/ContactSet%28guid%27<guid>%27%29"}' 'http://hostname/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/ListSet%28guid%27<guid>%27%29/$links/listcontact_association'
```

This is what I am receiving from the crm:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code>-2147220989</code>
  <message xml:lang="fi-FI">Invalid role specified for entity 'list'in relationship 'listcontact_association.Referenced'</message>
  <innererror>
    <message>Invalid role specified for entity 'list'in relationship 'listcontact_association.Referenced'</message>
    <type>System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<token>]]</type>
    <stacktrace>   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationDataServiceUpdateProvider.System.Data.Services.IUpdatable.SaveChanges()&#xD;
   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleNonBatchRequest(RequestDescription description)&#xD;
   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()</stacktrace>
  </innererror>
</error>
```

If I remove the `$links` parts, I get a different error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code></code>
  <message xml:lang="fi-FI">Error processing request stream. The property name 'URI' specified for type 'Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.List' is not valid.</message>
```

This would lead me to believe there is some other relationship that I should try to associate the person with, but I can't access the CRM to find this out, and the documentation wasn't really helpful :( Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure if this is doable through the REST endpoint. We've found cases where the SOAP endpoint offers functionality that the REST endpoint does not, and this might be one those cases.

What I did was to use the SOAP endpoint instead. There was no built in method for this, so I had to use the general one. That, in this case, was an organization request, where I had se the request name to "AddMemberList".

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the SDK call listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh372956.aspx)?

There example uses the SDK.REST.associateRecords function:

```
SDK.REST.associateRecords(parentAccount.AccountId,
    "Account",
    "Referencedaccount_parent_account",
    childAccount.AccountId,
    "Account");
```

Comment: From what I can tell, the curl command above accomplishes the same as this function would :/

Comment: It may, I've never used either before.